# How to use base64 encoded jpeg in Android gridview?

Tags: android, base64, bitmapfactory

I'm doing for testing purposes.
I have this image: [image]
I encoded it to base 64 using [this app](http://download.cnet.com/Base64-Encoder-Decoder/3000-10250_4-10555647.html) and the following is the result:

```
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
```

And I'm using the following code to turn it into bitmap:

```
String s = "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";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
```

And the following to set gridview content:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But all I'm getting is empty spots in my gridview! I wonder what is the problem?!

Comment: you are not converting your base64 to bytes. In fact you are just converting the base64's string into bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
byte[] decodedString;
decodedString = Base64.decode(s, Base64.DEFAULT);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And let me know what happen...

**String s is base64 string for image**..

Comment: I think your base64 image string is invalid because this code works fine in my case..